# use defineProperty from a module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Let's say in my module I have something like this :

```
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 
               'sayHello', {get: function(){ return "hello I'm an array" });
```

Now I would like to make this change visible to any scripts that import the module. Is this possible ?

I tried to modify the EXPORTED_SYMBOLS accordingly but I got no results so far.

Is there another way to achieve the same thing ? (i.e. load modules that add not enumerable properties to selected objects - like Array in the example above)

EDIT:

Following the comment below by Alnitak about `value:` and `get:` ...

I'm able now to define and use a property like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'firstId' , {value: function(){return this[0].id}});
var a = [{id:'x'},{id:'y'}]
a.firstId()
```

that returns as expected

```
x
```

Now: is it possible to put the defineProperty invocation in a module, load a module from a script  and expects that the Arrays of this script will act as the one above ?

EDIT2 :

I'm writing an application with xulrunner and I'm using Components.utils.import() to laod the module - I thought (probably wrongly) that the question could be put more generally ...

Comment: is `sayHello` supposed to be a function or a read-only value?

Comment: I would like to create both actually. I succeeded in doing this using defineProperty() but I cannot make it work by exporting from a module

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. I would like to have properties that return a read-only value and properties that returns a function

Comment: I mean, do you want to _call_ `myArray.sayHello()`, or obtain the string value of `myArray.sayHello` returned by that function.

Comment: ok, let's focus on calling myArray.sayHello()

Comment: so are you trying to say that creating this property on `Array.prototype` within a module _doesn't_ automatically add that property to _all_ Arrays?

Comment: yes, @Alnitak that's what I'm saying

Answer (score 0):

The `get:` type within a property descriptor can be used to supply a read-only value that's calculated at runtime:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'sayHello', {
    get: function() {
        return "hello I'm an array";
    }
});
```

Use `value:` if the property is just a read-only constant value:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'sayHello', {
    value: "hello I'm an array"
});
```

The usage of both of those is just:

```
var hello = myArray.sayHello;
```

You should also use the `value:` type to add a *function* as a non-enumerable property of a prototype, e.g.:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'sayHello', {
    value: function(o) {
        return "hello I'm an array";
    }
});
```

usage:

```
var hello = myArray.sayHello();
```

Likewise,

Comment: thanks for the clarification but I still have the problem to get this working from within a module. I'll edit the question to add a better example.

Comment: @lou I did wonder about that, but you had no info about what sort of environment this was in.